# loading foreign key data in drop down select name too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to show foreign key data as a drop down list, but we have a big data, the problem is it takes too long to load page that has the drop down field with the foreign key, is there a way to load it part by part?
here is my models.py

```
class Vistor(models.Model):
admin = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT,default=1)
full_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name=_('full name'))
dob = models.DateField(max_length=14,verbose_name=_('dob'))
city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name=_('city'))

class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['full_name','dob','city'],name='full_information')
    ]

def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.full_name} - {self.city} - {self.dob}'
```

and here is my views.py

```
def add_new_post(request):
    ...
    context = {
        'form':form,
        'room_number':room_number,
        'cities':City.objects.all(),
        'all_guests':Vistor.objects.all().order_by('-pk'), #the problem is here, has a big data
        }

    return render(request,'booking/add_booking.html',context)
```

and here is my templates

```html
      <div class="grid md:grid-cols-10 md:gap-5 child_formset_row" id="guests_no-${form_no}">
        <div class="col-span-5 groupinput relative bglightpurple mt-2 rounded-xl">
            <label class="text-white absolute top-1 mt-1 mr-2 text-xs">{% trans "full information" %}</label>
            <select name="guestinfo-0" id="guestinfo-0" class="visitors w-full pr-2 pt-6 pb-1 bg-transparent focus:outline-none text-white">
                <option value="-----">------</option>
                {% for c in all_guests %}
                <option value="{{ c.full_name }} - {{c.city}} - {{c.dob | date:'Y-m-d'}}">{{ c.full_name }} - {{c.city}} - {{c.dob | date:'Y-m-d'}}</option>
                {% endfor %}                                    
            </select>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-span-4 groupinput relative bglightpurple mt-2 rounded-xl">
            <label class="text-white absolute top-1 mt-1 mr-2 text-xs">{% trans "reason" %}</label>
            <input type="text" name="reason-0" id="reason-0" value="" required class="w-full pr-2 pb-1  pt-6 bg-transparent focus:outline-none text-white">
        </div> 
        <button type='button' class="col-span-1 flex items-center justify-center groupinput relative bglightpurple mt-2 rounded-xl" onclick="remove_form(this,${form_no})"><i class="text-red-600 far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        
    </div>
```

is there a way to load it part by part please ?
thank you so much for your helps ..

Comment: When you have too many options in a dropdown it begins to burden the user with a lot of time searching for an option, can be quite heavy on the front-end also as you have experienced. A good option would be to create a search-based dropdown field with ajax. As the user begins to type in a users name for example it will dynamically return the results to the frontend as options. See here: https://www.etemkeskin.com/index.php/2021/01/14/how-to-make-dynamic-dropdown-list-with-ajax-in-python-django/

Comment: @Lewis thank you for your reply, but it is not what im trying, its a booking system i've to prevent from adding duplicate names: contains : fullname, dob city, and dont want to spend time by selecting someone and see his/her city if it right then add it

Answer (score 2):

You can use [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/) along with leveraging Django forms to display that element.

This gives a searchable as well as scrollable dropdown that loads your data with a pagination type of concept.